# EF7 Multiple datacontext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I've got an Asp.Net 5 web application which use EF7 and SQL Server 2014. Now I need to make second DBContext which will connect to SQL Server 2008 R2. For some reason I'm able to connect but not able to get any data from database.

config.json:

```
"Data": {
"PMSConnectionString": "Data Source=xxxx;User ID=xxxx;Password=xxxx;Initial Catalog=xxxx;",
"MTOCL2ConnectionString": "Server=xxxx;Database=xxxx;User Id=xxxx;Password=xxxx;"
}
```

Startup.cs:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // Setup configuration sources.
        var configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("config.json")
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
     Configuration = configurationBuilder.Build();
    }



    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
        {
            options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver =
                new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
        });

        services.AddCaching(); // Adds a default in-memory implementation of IDistributedCache
        services.AddSession(s => s.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(360));

        services.AddEntityFramework()
            .AddSqlServer()
            .AddDbContext<MTOCL2Context>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:MTOCL2ConnectionString"])
                ).AddDbContext<PMSContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration["Data:PMSConnectionString"]))

            ;

    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.MinimumLevel = LogLevel.Information;
        loggerFactory.AddConsole();
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Append("Cache-Control", "private, no-store");
            await next();
        });

        app.UseSession();

        app.UseIISPlatformHandler();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
```

MTOCL2Context.cs:

```
public class MTOCL2Context:DbContext
{
    public DbSet<SubLotPriority> SubLotPriorities { get; set; }
}
```

UserController:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class UsersController : Controller
{
    private readonly PMSContext _dbContext;
    private readonly MTOCL2Context _dbContext2;

    public UsersController(MTOCL2Context dbContext2, PMSContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext2 = dbContext2;
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }
}
```

When I run application and try to get data from SubLotPriority, I get error:

> Evaluation of method System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView'1[[SublotPriority...

I actually don't get any error, when I go into dbcontext I don't get any results and error message appear on the screen. Don't know how to get full message:
[image: Error Message]

Comment: What is the rest of your error? Please provide the complete error with all sub-exceptions (if any) and relevant stack traces.

Comment: No, you do not get that when you *run* your application. The `..._DebugView` things are only used by the debugger.

Comment: Correct, this is what I get when I debug. I dont get any error when I run program. Picture added

Comment: Obviously the error appears when the query is actually executed, so for debuggings sake, just call `test.ToList()`, catch the resulting exception and tell us a story about the exception details.

Comment: When I add ToList(), nothing really happens. After about 3 minute of running I get OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Out of memory? well thats nice... sounds like you actually get some data. So what about `First()` or `Count()` instead of `ToList()` so you get a managable amount of data?

Comment: Wow, you actually right it works with First(). Thank you

Comment: Ok, so its actually working fine and you just need to ensure appropriate filtering, because it's impossible to handle the whole bulk of data at once. Problem solved or is your question still standing in some aspect?

Comment: yes, resolved. Thanks for your help